# LG G3 -504 bug (also cannot install .apk) of Facebook

Tags: facebook, 6.0-marshmallow, lg-g3

my friend has LG G3, recently updated to Android 6.0 Marshmallow and he gets -504 error code when he tries to install official Facebook app. I even tried to download .apk and tried multiple version but no progress. It doesn't looks like it's a gateway problem and he's pretty desperate. I looked at some answers and tried removing cache etc. but nothing has solved the problem. I look for any help.
Thanks very much for any reply.
-Feldrod

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Facebook, rebooting the phone, and re-installing it from the Play Store?

Comment: He can't install Facebook anyhow. He just has Facebook Messenger and that's all. He wants Facebook app.